# Can Arquillian deploy more than one applications for a single test?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I`m trying to use Arquillian framework for testing IBM WebSpehere 8.5.5 business applications (EJB3.1). I have successfully deployed my business ear which consists of MDB and few Session beans to the test IBM WAS, injected testing WAR into that ear and send a test message from my TestMsgSender to the MDB listener:

**MyArquillianTestCase.java**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class MyArquillianTestCase {
    @Deployment
    public static Archive createDeployment() throws InterruptedException {
        Archive testArch = createEarWithMavenResolver();
        printJarXml(testArch);
        return testArch;
    }

    @EJB
    TestMsgSender bean;

    @Test
    public void test() throws JMSException, NamingException, InterruptedException {
        bean.sendMessageUsingLookup();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    public static EnterpriseArchive createEarWithMavenResolver() {
        EnterpriseArchive ear = Maven.configureResolver().workOffline()
                .withMavenCentralRepo(false).resolve("my.business.ear.groupid:ear-artifact:ear:1.0.0").withoutTransitivity()
                .asSingle(EnterpriseArchive.class);
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClasses(TestMsgSender.class, MyArquillianTestCase.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        ear.addAsModule(war);
        updateAppXml(ear);
        return ear;
    }

    static EnterpriseArchive updateAppXml(EnterpriseArchive ear) {
        ...bunch of code here to update ear application XML (insert test.war),
        inner JARs (test JMS queues, active specs and other) ejb-jar.xml, ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml...
    }
}
```

**TestMsgSender.java**

```
@Stateless
public class TestMsgSender {
    public void sendMessageUsingLookup() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("jms/testlocal/not-queue/cf");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue requestQueue = (Queue) ic.lookup("jms/cell/request/queue");
            MessageProducer requestMsgProducer = session.createProducer(requestQueue);
            TextMessage txtRequestMsg = session.createTextMessage();
            txtRequestMsg.setText("Request message");
            requestMsgProducer.send(txtRequestMsg);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added Maven support for my test case using maven-surefire-plugin and all this works fine - I see my business ear deployed and reads a message which my test sender had sent to the corresponding queue. Now my question is if I can simultaneously deploy another ear (say ear-message-consumer) so that my.business.ear.groupid.ear-artifact-1.0.0.ear can pass the received message beyond to it?
Arquillian offers a feature of multiple deployment testing and I can edit a little my code for it:

```
@Deployment (name = "deployBusinessEar", order = 1)
public static Archive createDeploymentBusinessEar() {
    ...
}

@Deployment (name = "deployConsumerEar", order = 2)
public static Archive createDeploymentMessageConsumerEar() {
    ...
}

@Test @OperateOnDeployment("deployBusinessEar")
public void test() {
    ...
}
```

But it looks like I can use only corresponding test for each deployment  and not simultaneousely. According to testing logs and WAS logs I can say that WAS is starting undeploy the ear-message-consumer application when my test() method is still running :(
How can I deploy so much ear applications as I need and then test them all in a single test() method? Should I change any settings in arquillian.xml or pom.xml for my test?

Comment: The short answer is yes. We do it succesfully in an application with three deployments. However, our test framework is a combination of arquillian, spock, groovy and selenium deployed into docker and unfortunately I don't have the time to extract your answer out of that right now. 
Just wanted to let you know, it is possible :)

Looking into the javadoc of @OperateOnDeployment I see some possible hints for you: "Additionally you can reference another deployments metadata from within another context by qualifiing OperateOnDeployment on ArquillianResource injection points."

Comment: @Buurman sounds nice, thanks! I will try it